# Understanding lucene segments

Tags: lucene

I have these 3 files in a folder and they are all related to an index created by Lucene:

- _0.cfs
- segments_2
- segments.gen

What are they all used for, and is it possible to convert any of them to a human-readable format to discern a bit more about how lucene works with its indexes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two segments files store information about the segments, and the .cfs is a compound file consisting of other index files (like index, storage, deletion, etc. files).

For documentation of different types of files used to create a Lucene index, see this [summary of file extensions](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene40/package-summary.html#file-names)

Generally, no, Lucene files are not human readable.  They are designed more for efficiency and speed than human readability.  The way to get a human readable format is to access them through the Lucene API (via Luke, or Solr, or something like that).

If you want a thorough understanding of the file formats in use, the [codecs package](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene40/package-summary.html) would be the place to look.